# If she had known... - a question

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If he had known I was single, he would have asked me out.

Is this correct? In this case he had no idea I was single but he would have asked me out if he knew that. If not, how should I say that?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct, it is past perfect tense. If he had known in the past, he would have asked me, in the past. But he didn't know and he didn't ask.